# on Update Cascade in eloquent laravel is not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When I update the category of `skills`, the skill records won't be changed. I need to update all the records which are related to a category but update cascading doesn't work when `static::updating()` is called.

SkillModel:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Model;




class SkillsModel extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'skills';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany(
            SkillsModel::class,
            'category_id',
            'id');
    }


    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        static::deleting(function ($skills){
            $skills->categories()->delete();
        });

        static::restored(function ($skills){
            $skills->categories()->withTrashed()->restore();
        });

        static::updating(function ($skills){
            $skills->categories()->update();
            $s = 1;
        });


    }

}


***************
    private function save($model, $name, $category,$categoryId, $proficiency,$personal_info_id)
    {
        if ($name != null)
            $model->name = $name;
        if ($category != null)
            $model->category = $category;
        if ($proficiency != null)
            $model->proficiency = $proficiency;
        if ($personal_info_id != null)
            $model->personal_info_id = $personal_info_id;

        if ($categoryId != null){
            $model->category_id = $model->categoryId;
        }else{
            $model->save();
            $model->category_id = $model->id;

        }

        return $model->save();

    }
***************

      $isUpdated = $this->save(
            $this->skillRepo->find($request->getParam('id')),
            null,
            $request->getParam('category'),
            $request->getParam('categoryId'),
            null,
            $this->personalInfoRepo->getLastRecordId());
```

the Table ( this table has a self join to the category column):

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table skills
(
    id               int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name             varchar(200)                        null,
    category         varchar(200)                        not null,
    proficiency      int                                 null,
    created_at       timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    updated_at       timestamp                           null,
    deleted_at       timestamp                           null,
    personal_info_id int                                 not null,
    category_id      int                                 null,
    constraint fk12
        foreign key (personal_info_id) references admin_personal_information (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint fk13
        foreign key (category_id) references skills (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);

create index skills_admin_personal_information_index
    on skills (personal_info_id);

create index skills_index
    on skills (category_id);
```

Comment: Change Your ENGINE  `MyISAM` to `InnoDB`

Comment: you are calling the `update` method but are not passing in any values, what is it supposed to update?

Comment: @lagbox I want to update ```category``` column so where should I put the value?

Comment: you are trying to update the `category` column on what? you have a self referencing relationship so which one are you trying to update and with what value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess that you want to update all the `skills` that have the `category_id` of the current record to be updated with the value of `category` of the current model:

```
$skill->categories()->update(['category' => $skill->category]);
```

My guess of what you are asking about. This isn't going to be a recursive thing though, this is only 1 level. This is directly calling update on the database, it does not involve the models or model events.